# What should I use to display a jpg file in an OS X app? UIImage, CGImage or Image Kit?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks

I am confused by the availability of two set of widgets: `NSImageView` and `IKImageView` ('Image Kit Image View').

My goal is to load some jpg files from disk and display them. No editing is necessary.

Which widget or framework is more appropriate?

And I suppose `UIImage` is totally not applicable here because it is for iOS platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSImageView` for most normal cases.  `IKImageView` is for specialized cases, including allowing editing operations.

`NSImage` is the model object that you would use normally. `CGImage` is lower level and is sometimes used, but I would say only when a) some API you otherwise need to use naturally works with `CGImage`, or b) `CGImage` provides a capability not available from `NSImage`, `NSImageRep` or its subclasses (e.g. `NSBitmapImageRep`).

Yes, `UIImage` is not applicable for OS X.